# Using stored procedures in a Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, data-access-layer

I've got a simple application that reads from a database to set properties in a class and then output the result set to the screen as well as writing to a file.  I'm trying to plan ahead for my application to be a web application and would like for it to be designed close to as best practice as possible.  I would like to know if my DAL design has any major flaws, and if the way in which I take input from the user and set that to a parameter is normal or if there's a better way to do it.  Everything in the program does work as expected.

DAL

```
public static List<Customers> GetCustomersByName()
        {
            //make the list of the type that the method will be returning
            List<Customers> c = new List<Customers>();
            //make a connection string variable
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spFindCustomersByName",con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    //this stored procedure has one input parameter, how do I send that to the data access layer?
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    //only way I could think of to get the value entered from a screen into 
                    //a parameter
                    cmd.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = Customers.AddSpParams();

                    //instantiate SqlDataReader
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while(rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Customers custList = new Customers();
                        custList.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["customerId"]);
                        custList.LastName = rdr["lastName"].ToString();
                        custList.FirstName = rdr["firstName"].ToString();
                        custList.DateHired = (DateTime)rdr["dateHired"];
                        c.Add(custList);



                    }

                }
                return c;
            }
```

Method to assign value to the input parameter of the stored procedure

```
public static string AddSpParams()
        {
            Console.Write("Search for a string in customer's name: ");
            string nameParam = Console.ReadLine();
            return nameParam;
        }
```

writing to text file, writing to console

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is only a test");
            List<Customers> c = DataAccessCustomers.GetCustomersByName();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\customersList.txt"))
            {
                foreach(Customers custList in c)
                {
                    //write to console
                    Console.WriteLine(custList.CustomerId + "\t" + custList.FirstName + "\t" +
                        custList.LastName + "\t" + custList.DateHired);
                    //write to file
                    sw.WriteLine(custList.CustomerId + "\t" + custList.FirstName + "\t" +
                        custList.LastName + "\t" + custList.DateHired);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: This needs moved to Code Review instead.

Comment: I didn't know that existed.  How would I do that?

Comment: You can find that here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Basically, There is no problem with your design exception small point at here. I assume your store procedure and `Customer` class are not support null value. So, the main major flaw at here is your code still not handle DBNull value:

```
custList.LastName = rdr["lastName"].ToString();
custList.FirstName = rdr["firstName"].ToString();
custList.DateHired = (DateTime)rdr["dateHired"];
```

You should check DBNull value of rdr["lastName"] and rdr["firstName"]  before call `.ToString()` or boxing `(DateTime)rdr["dateHired"];` 
Hope this help.